# monotonicity for random walks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

Consider a simple symmetric random walk on the integers. Let $\mu(k,n)$ denote the probability of being at $k$ by step $n$. Say both $n,k$ are even. I'm interested in finding **"soft" proofs** (minimal computations, e.g. by coupling) of two facts.
First:
$$\mu(k,n) < \mu(0,n),$$
Second, for $k^2 \ll n$,
$$\frac{\mu(k,n) }{ \mu(0,n)} = 1 + O(k^2/n)$$

Of course, these are not too bad by direct computation, but I am interested in some specific variants of these inequalities where direct computation become quite cumbersome. Looking to hear other styles of arguing for random walks.

Comment: I do not know what counts as *soft*, but there is a central-limit-theorem-type of argument that $\mu(k,n)\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}  e^{- k^2 / (2n)}$  and so     $\frac{\mu(k,n) }{ \mu(0,n)} \approx e^{- k^2 /  (2n)}$, which for $k^2 \ll n$ is  $\approx 1-\frac12\frac{k^2}{n}$

Comment: Why don't you just tell us what variants you're interested in? Different variants may suggest quite different techniques.

Comment: For both questions it is relevant that $\mu(k,n)=0$ if $k \ne n \mod 2$.

Comment: @Henry agreed, that's what I'm trying to recover, except an LCLT has additive rather than multiplicative error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first inequality to hold, $n$ must be even, so I will assume that.
The inequality is much more general, holding for any symmetric walk:

Considering the location of the walk after $n/2$ steps, we obtain from Cauchy-Schwarz that
(all the summations are over all integers):

$$\mu(k,n)^2=\Bigl(\sum_x  \mu(x, n/2 ) \cdot \mu(k-x, n/2 ) \Bigr)^2 $$ $$\le
\sum_x  \mu(x, n/2 )^2 \cdot \sum_x \mu(k-x, n/2 )^2 $$ $$= 
\Bigl(\sum_x  \mu(x, n/2 )   \mu(-x, n/2 )  \Bigr)^2= \mu(0, n )^2 \,.$$